# Continuity of function of two variable by Epsilon-Delta technique.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

Given a function
$f(x,y)= \frac{x^3y^2+x}{x^2+y^2}$ when $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$. Show that the function $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(1,1)$ by Epsilon-Delta definition.

I can show it easily by the fraction of two continuous functions is continuous. But I need to prove it directly by Epsilon-Delta technique. I'm not able to think, how to do it. Please give some hint!

Effort: For any given $\epsilon>0$, we have
$|f(x,y)-1|= |\frac{x^3y^2+x}{x^2+y^2}-1|=|\frac{x^3y^2+x-x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}|$

Now, what's next?

Comment: What's about of starting writing the definition?

Comment: Definition I know for two variable but I need to prove the continuity for the given problem by Epsilon-Delta technique.

Comment: Start by writting the definition of $f$ being continuous at $(1,1)$. Then prove the resulting statement.

Comment: @Sachin: the "precise" continuity definition says: $f$ is continuous at $a\in {\rm Dom}(f)$ iff for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that if $|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon $. In your case $x=(x,y)$ and $a=(1,1)$.

Comment: Yes, I tried it but didn't get Delta.

Answer (score 1):

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
$\sqrt {(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2} < \delta \implies \left | \frac {x^3y^2 + x - x^2 - y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right | <\epsilon$

The numerator can be simplified and factored.

$(x^3-1)y^2 - x(x-1) = (x-1)((x^2+x+1)(y^2)-x)$

$(x-1) < \delta$

Let $\delta\le 1$

$|x|< 2, |y| < 2$

$|((x^2+x+1)(y^2)-x)| \le (4 + 2 + 1)(4) + 2 \le 30$

$x^2+y^2\ge 1$

$\left | \frac {((x^2+x+1)y^2-x)(x-1)}{x^2+y^2}\right | < 30\delta \le \epsilon$

$\delta = \min (1,\frac {1}{30}\epsilon)$